# Ignited Datatables Where Not In

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I using Ignited Datatables library but it dose not support WhereNotIn functionality, how can I add this feature to this library? Thanks in advance.

Comment: CodeIgniter do have this API. Make sure you have `active_record`(CodeIgniter 2.x) or `query_builder` (CodeIgniter 3.x) enabled in your database config.

Answer (score 1):

Patch the `Datatables` class like this:

```
class Datatables
{
  //...      
  private $where_not_in       = array();
  //...      

  public function where_not_in($key_condition, $val = NULL, $backtick_protect = TRUE)
  {
    $this->where_not_in[] = array($key_condition, $val, $backtick_protect);
    $this->ci->db->where_not_in($key_condition, $val, $backtick_protect);
    return $this;
  }      

  private function get_total_results($filtering = FALSE)
  {
  //...      
    foreach($this->where_not_in as $val)
      $this->ci->db->where_not_in($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
  //...      
  }
}
```